# how to draw airbrush on UIImageView?

Tags: iphone

I am a beginner working on paint application on iphone.

adding new tool for my iphone App called airbrush...

which will spray on UIImageView. can any one help me out how to work with it.

Comment: What do you mean by Chalk line?

Comment: thanks plumenator for replay....

actually i want to draw airbrush  on my UIImageView...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be looking for `CGContextBeginPath` and its related functions. I am not quite sure how to define a new stroke but I imagine it can be handled with something like `[UIColor colorFromImage:myImage]`. You should look into Quartz 2D, try looking [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-TPXREF101).

/Thomas

Comment: It's not going to be a walk in the park. You should be able to make a custom pen (stroke) somehow using the Quartz 2D API. If you cannot find the functionality in the API for that, my best guess would be that you can load an image (round white for chalk) and continuously paint it to the image when a user touches the image. You are going to have to use `touchesBegan:withEvent:` on an UIResponder or you can make a Gesture Recognizers: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html

Comment: Thanks Thomas.......

Its Working.......

I used UIBezierpath...

I got my airbrush :D

Comment: Great! Good luck with the rest of your app.

Comment: Thanks Thomas....

Now i am adding new tool for my application .. "Smudge brush" 

is any document regarding smudge. 

I need to raise a new question for smudge brush.

Answer (score 7):

```
Logic for air brush.........

- (UIBezierPath *)pathFromPoint:(CGPoint)start toPoint:(CGPoint)end {

    CGFloat lineWidth=10;
    redrawRect = CGRectMake(end.x-lineWidth,end.y-lineWidth,lineWidth*2,lineWidth*2);
    UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    UIBezierPath *circle = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:redrawRect];
    NSInteger i, x, y;

    NSInteger modNumber =4*(int)lineWidth;
    for (i = 0; i < (lineWidth*lineWidth)/2; i++) {
        do {
            x = (random() % modNumber)+end.x - 2*lineWidth;
            y = (random() % modNumber)+end.y - 2*lineWidth;
        } while (![circle containsPoint:CGPointMake(x,y)]);

        [bezierPath appendPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(x,y,0.5,0.5)]];
    }
    return bezierPath;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    currentPoint.y -=20;
    [self drawCircle];
}
-(void)drawCircle{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.drawImage.frame.size);
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0, drawImage.frame.size.width, drawImage.frame.size.height)]; //originally self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),10);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    UIBezierPath *path=[self pathFromPoint:currentPoint 
                                   toPoint:currentPoint];
    [path stroke];
    lastPoint = currentPoint;
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Comment: In drawCircle method, maybe you mean: UIBezierPath *path=[self pathFromPoint:lastPoint toPoint:currentPoint]; ?